# Open a bitmap with Inputstream

Tags: java

How would I open a bitmap with Inputstream?

e.g `InputStream inputStream = image` where image is of type `Bitmap`?

Thanks.

Comment: "image is of type Bitmap" what does that mean ? Is that a java class name, or are you refering to the BMP format ? A inputstream is for reading just a sequence of bytes. Do you want to load a file, just as is or decoded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the bitmap image in your app,
 `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.load("mybitmap.bmp");`

To get the pixels from the buffered image object, use `getRGB()`

```
int[] pixels = img.getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null, 0, img.getWidth());
```

javadoc for [getRGB()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

For more info, see [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip43.html) article.

Answer (score 2):

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("source.bmp"));
```

Is this what you need ?

Answer (score 2):

```
            if (thumbnail != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos .toByteArray());
            }
```

try this