# How to get inputstream from bitmap image file?

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream

i am developing one contact application . I want to show contact image to my custom listview . I want to get Inputstream from that contact image to write into sdcard . How can i get it ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please check below link, hope this will help u:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280308/open-a-bitmap-with-inputstream

Comment: But my image file is not stored in sdcard or internal memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied verbatim from the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.html):

```
 public InputStream openDisplayPhoto(long photoFileId) {
     Uri displayPhotoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_URI, photoKey);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(
             displayPhotoUri, "r");
         return fd.createInputStream();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return null;
     }
 }
```